# the scrollview is not correctly working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new in iOS programming, and my scroll view is not scrolling horizontally.

I want to make it possible to scroll horizontally, vertically it works correctly, but horizontally it not working please help me. I used the following code.

```
 scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 460);
 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 678)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the frame of scrollview is  CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) and content size is [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 678)]; because scroll is enabled when the scroll content size is greater then the frame size of scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Try the following . this is working code for me . I am adding the images on horizontal scroll view .

```
        int scrollWidth=60;
        for (int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
        {
            UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth,8,50,40)];
            imageView1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            imageView1.backgroundColor=[array objectAtIndex:i];
            [scrollView addSubview:imageView1];
            scrollWidth=scrollWidth+80;
        }

        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 30)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the width 600 but the content size is 320 so in that case you can't scroll horizontally. So you need to set width of content.

```
 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 678)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(600,678);
```